# Dynamic casting using result of NSClassFromString("MyUIViewController")

Tags: swift

I'm finding that the following code does not work, but I don't exactly understand why.

Say I have a class name saved in a string. I want to cast a view controller as the class that this string refers to.

```
let controller = self.navigationController as! NSClassFromString("MyUIViewController")
```

Swift doesn't seem to understand this - I get this error:

```
Undeclared use of NSClassFromString.
```

Or the error:

```
Consecutive statements must be separated by `,`
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case? I can't cast (using as?) a type based on some variable?

Thanks

Comment: Not that straight forward in Swift, you may wanna check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373030/how-to-create-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string-in-swift-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot cast to a runtime type object. You must cast to a compile-time type. This is why we write `x as Int`, not `x as Int.self`: `Int` is a type, and `Int.self` is an object that represents that type at runtime.

What would it mean to cast to `NSClassFromString("MyUIViewController")`? Now you have a variable, `controller`, whose value is some type that the compiler knows nothing about, so the compiler cannot let you do anything with `controller`. You can't call methods or access properties on it, because the compiler doesn't know what methods or properties it has. You can't pass it as an argument to a function, because the compiler doesn't know whether it is the right type for that argument.

If you edit your question to explain what you want to do with `controller` (what methods you want to call on it or what properties you want to access or what functions you want to pass it to), then I will revise my answer to address your goal.