# Get class type dynamically from string for JSONDecoder.decode()

Tags: swift, swift4

I want to decode json responses of a websocket "notification" where the type of notification is within the json response.

JSON example:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "Application.OnVolumeChanged",
    "params": {
        "data": {
            "muted": false,
            "volume": 88.6131134033203125
        },
        "sender": "xbmc"
    }
}
```

This is what I currently have:

```
func notificationMessage(text: String) {
    do {
        if let jsonData = text.data(using: .utf8),
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as? [String: Any],
            let method = json["method"] as? String,
            let methodName = method.split(separator: ".").last?.description {

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let object = try decoder.decode(OnVolumeChanged.self, from: jsonData)

            print(object)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Now I somehow want to use `methodName` instead of `OnVolumeChanged.self`.
But I don't feel like making a huge switch case on the methodName since I can get like hundreds of diferent methods
I have tried `NSClassFromString(methodName)` but this is giving me `AnyClass?` which is not a concrete type.

Is there a way to get a class type from string?

Comment: Have you tried `NSClassFromString(method)` instead of stripping the namespace part of the `method` string?

Comment: ``decode()`` is expecting a concrete type ``T.Type`` and ``AnyClass?`` is basically anything.

Comment: This goes against Swift's static typing system so you will have to swim against a pretty strong current. But before you do that, ask yourself: is there any difference that you want to capture for `OnVolumeChanged` and `AnotherMethodName`? If so, please edit your question to add an example.

Comment: I had the same issue for matching JSON to class types, and I ended up using enumerations with raw values matching the JSON string values.

Comment: Yes @CodeDifferent, the data object within the json is diferent for every method. But i'll stick to an enum containing all possible methods and then determine with a switch case which object should be used for decoding the json. Thanks for information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have faced the same problem and here is my solution. You can add
>   methods to Mapper dictionary any time you want.

//1

```
let Mapper: [String: Any] = ["OnVolumeChanged"  : OnVolumeChanged.self]
```

//2

```
func notificationMessage(text: String) {
                    do {
                        if let jsonData = text.data(using: .utf8),
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as? [String: Any],
                            let method = json["method"] as? String,
                            let methodName = method.split(separator: ".").last?.description {

                            let className = Mapper[methodName] as! Codable.Type
                            let object = try className.init(jsonData: jsonData)


                            print(object)
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
                    }
                }
```

//3

```
extension Decodable {
                    init(jsonData: Data) throws {
                        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: jsonData)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: there is nothing "dynamic" in this solution, there should be a solution where we don't need to manually enter all the classes we auto generated for json responses, even supplying the "decoder" utility with the expected json response and do `Bundle.main.classNamed("MyClassName")` is better, (like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55170964/530884)