# Call Swift function from Bundle

Tags: swift, bundle, bundles

I have declared a function in a custom bundle using Xcode and Swift.

MyBundle.bundle —> File.swift —> `func …() {}`

How do I call that function from another project using `Foundation.Bundle`?

Comment: You can cast it to the actual type. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/40373130/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Unfortunately I cannot do this as I do not have access to the implementation in my code. I know the names of the functions only because *I wrote them*. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can't call it directly but probably you can make some way around that might work.

You can create an instance of that class from string using `NSClassFromString` and then you call the method using that call

Something like below

```
func getClassName(_ strClassName: String) -> AnyClass! {
   let bundle = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String;
    let requiredClass: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(strClassName)")!;
    return requiredClass;
}
```

Then you can call the method using your class instance returned by the above method like

```
yourClassInstance.perform(Selector("functionName"))
```

Comment: Conform the class to NSObject and declare it and the method with `@objc(ClassOrMethodName)`. Cast the class loaded from bundle to NSObject.Type and then perform the selector as you said. Thanks!