# Bidirectional data exchange between macOS Bundles (swift)

Tags: swift, bundle, foundation

How can I pass data between macOS Bundles?

eg: MyApp.app sends data to a function or class initialiser in MyBundle.bundle, which performs its own logic on it. It could even return a value, which MyApp.app can then process further.

Fo example, a function in MyBundle (not nested in any other declaration):

```
    void initialise(unsigned int frameCount) {…} // not a class initialiser btw
```

I have tried:

- Declaring a class in MyBundle and then loading it in MyApp using `Foundation.Bundle`:

  ```
  let class = (Bundle(url: url)!.classNamed("MyClass")! as! NSObject.Type).init()
  // class is an instance of NSObject, but I can override the `init()` method 
  // (in MyBundle) to do whatever. I have not found a way to implement an 
  // initialiser with parameters, and it still be recognised here.
  ```
- Declaring a function in MyBundle and using `CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName` to retrieve it.

  ```
  var bundles = CFBundleCreateBundlesFromDirectory(kCFAllocatorDefault, bundleDirectory, bundleExtension)! as Array
  var bundle1 = bundles.first! as! CFBundle

  var untypedFunctionPointer = CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(bundle, "initialise" as CFString)!

  let imp = unsafeBitCast(untypedFunctionPointer, to: IMP.self)

  let function = unsafeBitCast(imp, to: (@convention(c)(CUnsignedInt) -> Void).self)
  // If I specify parameters here, pass them in below, then try to use them in my objective c function, I get exc_bad_access.

  function(CUnsignedInt(1.0)) // Will work only when not trying to access parameters in the original objective c function.



  // Whatever @convention(c) function signature I use, the parameters are unusable in Objective C.
  ```

The critical issue with both is that I am *unable to pass data in as parameters*. So a print statement will work but no ability to use arguments.

**Edit**: Accepted answer shows the correct method for calling function pointers. The crashes I talked about are a result of using types which are not being bridged to the C family of languages properly, so stick to NSNumber, NSString etc. from the Foundation library when in doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question [Call Swift function from Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62072631/5329717) and comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56281093/5329717 I presume you're after dynamically invoking in Swift a function pointer or an objective-c method with `UnsafeBufferPointer` argument.

First of all `UnsafeBufferPointer` will make a copy so for interoping I recommend switching to `OpaquePointer` instead.

Assuming function to pointer case with signature `void cFunction(void* arg)`:

```
let fakeIMP = unsafeBitCast(functionToPointerAddress, to: IMP.self)
unsafeBitCast(fakeIMP,to:(@convention(c)(OpaquePointer)->Void).self)(bufferArg)
```

Assuming static objective-c method:

```
let receiverClass = NSClassFromString("SomeClass")
let selector: Selector = NSSelectorFromString("selectorArg:")
let methodIMP: IMP! = method_getImplementation(class_getClassMethod(receiverClass, selector))
unsafeBitCast(methodIMP,to:(@convention(c)(AnyClass?,Selector,OpaquePointer)->Any).self)(receiverClass,selector, bufferArg)
```

For your provided C signature

```
void initialise(unsigned int frameCount);
```

Try this:

```
let imp = unsafeBitCast(functionToPointerAddress, to: IMP.self)
unsafeBitCast(imp,to:(@convention(c)(Int)->Void).self)(1)
```

Comment: @Div Please include the original C function / objective-C method signature in your question

Comment: Many thanks for showing this technique. Turns out that the crash was a result of using types incompatible with Objective-C and Foundation, so for now I will only be using NSNumber, NSArray etc.