# Swift reconstructing subclasses from dictionary/plist

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

I am reading dictionary from a plist file and based on the object type I want to construct and initialize objects of appropriate class. Here is my code:

```
 enum ItemType:String {
    case type1, type2, type3, type4,...
 }

 class SuperItem {
    var type:ItemType 

    init?(_ dictionary:[String:Any]) {
      if let typeString = dictionary["type"] as? String, let type = ItemType(typeString) {
        self.type = type 
      } else {
         return nil
      } 
    }
    ...
 }


 class TypeOneItem: SuperItem {
    override var type:ItemType = .type1
    ...
   
 }

 class TypeTwoItem: SuperItem {
    override var type:ItemType = .type2
    ...
 }
```

My problem is when I am initialising with dictionary in SuperItem, if type == type1 it should initialize and return object of type TypeOneItem instead of SuperItem, and so on for other types. Is there any way to achieve this in Swift?

Comment: How to create an instance of a class from a String in Swift https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373030/how-to-create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string-in-swift

Comment: This is close but not the same as it assumes class name mapping from String.

Comment: Create a separate factory method that first creates the enum type and then in a switch creates the correct subclass depending on type using the constructor for that subclass, like `case type2: return TypeTwoItem()`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You mean a class method inside SuperItem class?

Comment: Yes a class/static method and it can really be anywhere, inside SuperItem or a separate class

Comment: That works but it adds a little confusion by having it alongside SuperItem.init?(_ dictionary). The init method is used by subclasses.

Comment: Not sure what you do in that init method but if we only talk about what is done in the posted code then the init in the superclass should be removed since that logic is handled by the factory method. And `var type:ItemType` isn't needed either.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ok the init(_ dictionary) in superclass implements common functionality that is required for init(_ dictionary) in subclass. How do we tackle it then? I would need to duplicate code in every subclass it means

Comment: No of course not, I was only going by the code posted in the question. Common stuff should be handled in the superclass.